# Error divide by zero by estimating an EGARCH model

Tags: python

I want to estimate an EGARCH model with a student-t distribution. When I do this I get the error that I divide by zero.

The formula for sigma^2 is:
$$log(\sigma^2_t) = w + \sum_{i=1}^a \alpha_i g(z_{t-i}) + \sum_{i=1}^p \beta_i log (\sigma^2_{t-i})$$.
Hence to come to sigma, I take the exponential function.

```
def garch_filter(omega, alpha, g, beta, eps):
    iT = len(eps)
    sigma_2 = np.zeros(iT)

    for i in range(iT):
        if i==0:
            sigma_2[i] = np.exp(np.var(eps))
        else:
            sigma_2[i] = np.exp(omega + alpha*(np.abs(eps[i-1])/sigma_2[i-1] - math.sqrt(2/math.pi)) + g*eps[i-1]/sigma_2[i-1] + beta*np.log(sigma_2[i-1]))
    return sigma_2


def garch_loglike(vP, eps):
    iT = len(eps)
    omega = vP[0]
    alpha = vP[1]
    g = vP[2]
    beta = vP[3]
    v = vP[4]

    sigma_2 = garch_filter(omega, alpha, g, beta, eps)

    logL = -(len(eps)*np.log((gamma((v+1)/2))/(math.sqrt(3.14*(v-2)) *gamma(v/2)))-0.5*np.sum(np.log(sigma_2)) - ((v+1)/2) * np.sum(np.log(1+eps**2/(sigma_2*(v-2)))))
    return logL
```

I want to maximize the loglikelihood, that's why I minimize logL. 
What's the reason that I divide by zero in the formula for sigma_2. sigma_2 is always greater than zero, right?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check if `sigma_2*(v-2)` equals zero

Comment: No, that is not it. If I print sigma_2, sometimes it is zero

Comment: _sometimes it is zero_ so there you have found the cause of your issue

Comment: Yes, but why it is zero? Because I take the exponential

Comment: _why it is zero?.._ Don't know.. debug your code step by step